# Define a variable dependant finction in differential equations in PyDSTool

Tags: python

I am completely new in 'PyDSTool' so excuse me if it seems silly. I want to define two nonlinear differential equations in 'PyDSTool'. There is a nonlinear function that takes a variable as input:

```
  S(x1) = 1/(1+exp(x1-a))
```

So I wrote:

```
from PyDSTool import *
icdict = {'x':0,'y':0.2}
pardict = {
  'c1': 16.0,
  'c2': 12,
  'c3':15,
  'c4':3,
  'ax':1.3,
  'ay':2.,
  'rx':1.,
  'ry':1.,
  'P':1.25,
  }

def Func(x,a): #nonlinear function
  return (['x'],'1./(1. + exp(x-%.2f))'% a)

auxfndic = {'funx': Func(c1*x -c2*y+P,ax),'funy': Func(c3*x -c4*y,ay)}
xstr = ' (-x + (1 - rx * x)* funx(x,y))'
ystr = ' (-y + (1 - ry * y)* funy(x,y))'
vardict = {'x': xstr,'y':ystr}

DSargs = args()
DSargs.name = 'test_Equations'
DSargs.ics = icdict
DSargs.pars = pardict
DSargs.tdata = [0, 200]
DSargs.varspecs = vardict

DS = Generator.Vode_ODEsystem(DSargs)

traj = DS.compute('test')
pts = traj.sample()

plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['x'], 'k', label='x')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

`c1` can not be read by the function.

```
  NameError: name 'c1' is not defined
```

I don't know how to define `Func` inside the ODE that takes a variable as input. Thanks for any guide.

**Edit**

```
...
def Func(x,a): #nonlinear function
  return (['x'],'1./(1. + exp(x-%.2f))'% a)


auxfndic = {'funx': lambda x,y,c1,c2: Func(c1*x -c2*y+P,ax),
            'funy': lambda x,y,c3,c4: Func(c3*x -c4*y,ay)}
xstr = ' (-x + (1 - rx * x)* funx(x,y))'
ystr = ' (-y + (1 - ry * y)* funy(x,y))'
vardict = {'x': xstr,'y':ystr}

DSargs = args()
DSargs.name = 'test_Equations'
DSargs.ics = icdict
DSargs.pars = pardict
DSargs.fnspecs = auxfndic
DSargs.tdata = [0, 200]
DSargs.varspecs = vardict    
DS = Generator.Vode_ODEsystem(DSargs)
traj = DS.compute('test')
pts = traj.sample()
plt.plot(pts['t'], pts['x'], 'k', label='x')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The same error.

Answer (score 2):

This obviously won't work:

```
auxfndic = {'funx': Func(c1*x -c2*y+P,ax),'funy': Func(c3*x -c4*y,ay)}
```

`c1` really isn't defined. You defined `paradict['c1']`. If you want to define parameterized wrapper functions for func you need stuff like:

```
lambda x,c1,c2: Func(c1*x -c2*y+P,ax),
```

This defines a function on the fly that can accept parameters, but obviously still needs an `x`. You can define your auxfndic like this.

Since you don't use it in your code I'm not how you would proceed.

Comment: Thanks, `DSargs.fnspecs = auxfndic` was missed,  I changed the function like this: `auxfndic = {'funx': lambda x,c1,c2: Func(c1*x -c2*y+P,ax),
            'funy': lambda x,c3,c4: Func(c3*x -c4*y,ay)}`, and still have this error: `auxinfo tuple must be of length 2`

Comment: I tried this : `auxfndic = {'funx':(['x','y'],'1./(1. + exp((c1*x -c2*y+P)-ax))'),
            'funy':(['x','y'],'1./(1. + exp((c3*x -c4*y)-ay))')}` and it worked. but I still want to learn the other way.